# Understanding StarCraft II without having played Starcraft I

Tags: starcraft-2

How much will I miss of the StarCraft II plot if I have not played the original?

Halo 3 is the worst offender thus far in this respect - things are not explained for gamers who did not slog through the first two parts.

Is SC2 the same, or does Blizzard actually take new players into account?

Comment: Not much given that I don't understand a lot from playing SCI

Answer (score 14, accepted):

During the install, the Adjutant describes the events of the first game in an overview fashion to get you caught up.  In addition, they do a good job of giving you key information from the first game throughout whenever they reference events from it.

Starcraft II does have its own plot that is not entirely dependent on the first game, so they went to lengths to ensure that you need not have played the first one to fully enjoy the second one.

Comment: Exactly. Not knowing SC1 will not be a problem. On the other hand you also wont be able to fully appreciate all the twists in the story, since some have roots in the original game.

Comment: Adding to that: Tychus (or whatever his name was, the big space marine guy) works as a medium to give you info about the events of SC 1. He was not part of the SC 1 story and the characters in SC 2 have to explain everything to him, giving you all the necessary info to follow the SC 2 story.

Comment: In case you missed it during install, see [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4094/is-it-possible-to-watch-the-summary-story-that-is-told-during-the-install-of-star).

Comment: I think the instruction manual does a better job of explaining the plot than the installer.  You need the boxed copy (not the electronic copy) for that, though.

Comment: @Kyralessa:  The electronic copy doesn't come with the instruction manual, the Jim Raynor notepad, or the two Starcraft 2 and two WoW guest passes.

Answer (score 0):

SC2 is definitely playable even tough you didn't play the first chapter.

That said I think that sympathizing with Raynor is much easier if you played SC1. Overall if you played SC1 you get a sense of "being in the family" that you can't have otherwise. Apart from that you can enjoy 100% SC2.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to these answers, if you have no experience with Blizzard RTS games (SC1, Warcraft3), a lot of the game play will be new to you. People who have played these games have the advantage of being able to come in and know the interface and a lot of the hotkeys (although most are remapped in SC2). As an old SC1 player and old WC3 player, I was able to come into SC2 mostly pre-trained in how to operate the game. I'm not a great player by ANY means, but it did give me a leg up.