# Is it possible to watch the summary story that is told during the install of Starcraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

The installation process finished before the story recap thing that was being told did and I haven't been able to find an option to replay that.

Is it possible to watch that after the game has been installed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The video is available in two parts on this [Join the Dominion!](http://us.starcraft2.com/dominion/) website.  The two parts are called "New Era" and "Uncertain Future."  As of this writing, they were easily accessible on the right side of the linked site.

Answer (score 6):

For what it's worth, the starcraft 2 manual comes with a 5-page, "extended" version of the in-game history, covering things the installer leaves out, such as the UED invasion. (i.e, Brood War's storyline). The text can be found on pages 8 - 12.